# C++ open source console program

Tags: c++, open-source, console-application

I am looking for a `C++` console open source program, which uses inheritance and virtual functions, polymorphism to test my cryptographic software on it. 
Mainly, how it will handle virtual functions etc.
So far it was tested only on `C` programs, so any help would be appreciated. 
I know, that there is google and this is a bit off-topic but believe me, i googled a lot of days, yet could not find console `C++` program. The ones i found had GUI - so i could not really test them automaticly.

Comment: Sorry, but questions asking for tool recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: @JohnDibling i know, was just a bit desperate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can find what you need in Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Free_software_programmed_in_C%2B%2B

f/e rTorrent: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTorrent

Comment: guys, don't downvote him please, I asked off-topic question, so downvote me, if you feel that is necessacy. And by the way, this is helpfull. RTorrent seems like a solution, there is indeed all what i need, thank a lot.